# ora-00907 missing right parenthesis in subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery, ora-00907

oracle shows error: ora-00907 missing right parenthesis

```
SELECT EQUIPMENT_ID
    FROM IRRI_EQUIPMENT_STATUS_CHANGE
   WHERE ID IN(SELECT MAX (ID)
                    FROM IRRI_EQUIPMENT_STATUS_CHANGE
                   WHERE STAUS_YEAR_MONTH <= 105
                GROUP BY EQUIPMENT_ID, STAUS_YEAR_MONTH
                ORDER BY MAX (ID) ASC, STAUS_YEAR_MONTH DESC)
ORDER BY EQUIPMENT_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` in `IN` clause query is not required and also it serves no purpose and throws error.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT EQUIPMENT_ID
    FROM IRRI_EQUIPMENT_STATUS_CHANGE
   WHERE ID IN(SELECT MAX (ID)
                    FROM IRRI_EQUIPMENT_STATUS_CHANGE
                   WHERE STAUS_YEAR_MONTH <= 105
                GROUP BY EQUIPMENT_ID, STAUS_YEAR_MONTH)
ORDER BY EQUIPMENT_ID
```

Cheers!!